# Error: Can't create train working dir: catboost_info

Tags: python, catboost

I have been following the linked tutorial to build a catboost classifier model:

https://www.analyseup.com/python-machine-learning/catboost-python-tutorial.html

The code is working well up until I try to run the 13th command in the tutorial:

```py
model.grid_search(grid,train_dataset)
```

at which point I receive the following error:

```
CatBoostError: catboost/libs/train_lib/dir_helper.cpp:20: Can't create train working dir: catboost_info
```

Answer (score 0):

`catboost_info` is the name of the output folder catboost writes to track logs (See https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/output-data.html).

> The directory for the output files is specified in the train-dir
> (train_dir) parameter. The default value for the parameter is
> catboost_info.

**Try to change the environment you are working in that allows catboost to write the `catboost_info` folder, or specify a path where to write the output file.**

I had this issue working in Databricks (using CatBoostClassifier), I copied the same code to my personal computer and it worked locally because it was able to write the `catboost_info` folder in my working directory.

After running a model more than once you will receive
`Custom logger is already specified. Specify more than one logger at same time is not thread safe.` This is due to the logger info that is written to this catboost_info folder, it is only a warning and won't effect your modeling.

---

catboost_info folder:
[Click to see what is inside output folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IudQY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `allow_writing_files=False` should solve the issue if you don't have write access.

Example

```py
CatBoostClassifier(
   # some params
   allow_writing_files=False
)
```